# Scraping HTML by Class in VBA

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname, vba

I have a html code as shown

```html
<div class="property-title visible-xs">
                                        <a href="/property/473902/Office-Lot">
                                            <h2><b> 2nd Floor, Block D5, Solaris Dutamas, No. 1, Jalan Dutamas 1, 50480, Kuala Lumpur</b></h2>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p style="color: #0071ee;">Office Lot</p>
                                    <h4><b>RM 880,000</b></h4>
                                    <div>
                                        <table>
                                        <!-- <tr><td>Office Lot</td></tr> -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Property Code</td><td>:</td><td>PB473902</td>
                                            </tr>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>Auction Date</td><td>:</td><td>2016-02-26</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                <td>Built up  </td><td>:</td><td>754 sq.ft  </td>
                                            </tr>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>Tenure</td><td>:</td><td>Freehold</td>
                                                </tr>
```

and I used the following code to extract the details "2nd Floor, Block D5,...."

objIE1.Document.getElementsByClassName("property-title visible-xs").getElementsByTagName ("a")

but it don't seem to get the result I need. Please help.

The html code shown is in multiple form.

Comment: Try adding a `(0)` to the end of the line of code e.g. `objIE1.Document.getElementsByClassName("property-title visible-xs").getElementsByTagName ("a")(0)` so it takes the first "a" element in the element collection.

Comment: Hi I tried as follows:                                                                          extract1 = objIE1.Document.getElementsByClassName("property-title visible-xs").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

Cells(1, 1).Value = extract1                                                                              but it got an error 438 which states that object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: did the below answer resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
extract1 = objIE1.Document.getElementsByClassName("property-title visible-xs")(0).getElementsByTagName ("a")(0).innerText
Cells(1,1).Value = extract1
```

When a function has `getElementsBy` (plural - "Elements") such as `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` the code will extract a collection of elements so you need to specify which one you want, in this case it is the first which in `html` is `0`. When a function uses `getElementBy` (singular - "Element") such as `getElementById` this extracts a single element and therefore does not need an index specification as there is no collection.